# Materials with Texture mapping not displaying properly when trying to bake

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking

I am trying to bake multiple materials into 1 image, and i have been following a few tutorials, mainly this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9airvjDaVh4&t=393s

I have some procedural textures, and i am trying to follow along, plugging in a UV map node into the mapping node, but for some reason, my surface imperfections disappears and ends up looking wrong. This happens when i try this with my normal maps as well, though i think that is a different issue entirely. This is what i see:

[image: Small minor scratches]

Once i plug in the UV map node:

[image]

It has these streaks that appear. I know it has to do with the texture coordinate node, but if that is the case, then how do i solve this issue? How can i bake these in?

Here is my file: https://www.mediafire.com/file/3r9pny8q875wr1e/Epiphone+Casino+J.blend/file

Thank you